# Using Podman with docker-compose, how to get multiple replicas of a service

Tags: docker-compose, podman

**EDIT**: weird DNS behavior was some kind of transient issue, and now RHEL/podman works the same way as Ubuntu/podman. I can't reproduce the issue, which makes most part (not 100% though) of this question moot.

I am trying to use Podman and docker-compose to create a compose stack with multiple replicas of backend container, and having a hard time with it.

I use Podman because I have to (comes from Red Hat platform), and picked docker-compose because it is familiar and I use in local dev host, too. I know there are alternatives (podman-compose etc). I learned that Podman 4.1 supported Docker Compose so this sounded like a good candidate.

As an example I have docker-compose.yml with one frontend container and 3 backend containers:

```
version: "3"
services:
  frontend:
    image: "nginx:latest"
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
    depends_on:
      - backend
  backend:
    image: "tomcat:latest"
    ports:
      - "8180-8280:8080"
    scale: 3
```

**Note:** this stack is just an example. It's purpose is only to highlight the networking aspects of multi-replica docker-compose . I could use something else than `nginx:latest`, and using e.g. Traefik can solve some of the problems...but sometimes you wish to connect directly from one container to a service with multiple container replicas.

## Docker & docker-compose (Ubuntu)

Running this on host which has docker and docker-compose is straightforward.

Backend containers get assigned random ports from range 8180-8280.

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE           COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                       NAMES
98941117708c   nginx:latest    "/docker-entrypoint.…"   25 seconds ago   Up 22 seconds   0.0.0.0:3000->80/tcp, :::3000->80/tcp       example-docker-compose-frontend-1
3d749e25eaba   tomcat:latest   "catalina.sh run"        26 seconds ago   Up 23 seconds   0.0.0.0:8193->8080/tcp, :::8193->8080/tcp   example-docker-compose-backend-1
854ba8f60cb3   tomcat:latest   "catalina.sh run"        26 seconds ago   Up 23 seconds   0.0.0.0:8192->8080/tcp, :::8192->8080/tcp   example-docker-compose-backend-2
e57e32181e8e   tomcat:latest   "catalina.sh run"        26 seconds ago   Up 23 seconds   0.0.0.0:8194->8080/tcp, :::8194->8080/tcp   example-docker-compose-backend-3
```

Logging into frontend container, service name backend resolves to all 3 backend containers

```
dig backend

; <<>> DiG 9.16.27-Debian <<>> backend
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 31602
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;backend.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
backend.        600 IN  A   172.19.0.3
backend.        600 IN  A   172.19.0.2
backend.        600 IN  A   172.19.0.4
```

`curl backend:8080` works

## Podman & docker-compose (RHEL 8)

Podman came preinstalled, I added docker-compose (standalone) and podman-docker:

```
# curl -SL https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.10.2/docker-compose-linux-x86_64 -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
# chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
# sudo yum install podman-docker
```

And activated rootless podman socket so that podman and docker-compose can talk to each other:

```
# systemctl --user enable podman.socket
# systemctl --user start podman.socket
# systemctl --user status podman.socket
# export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///run/user/$UID/podman/podman.sock
```

I also switched network backend to netavark, DNS did not work without that change

```
$ podman info |grep -i networkbackend
  networkBackend: netavark
```

### 1. Port ranges are not supported

Podman does not like ports: - "8180-8280:8080" due to this bug: https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/15111

```
[+] Running 1/0
 ⠿ Network example-docker-compose_default      Created                           0.0s
 ⠋ Container example-docker-compose-backend-3  Creating                          0.0s
 ⠋ Container example-docker-compose-backend-1  Creating                          0.0s
 ⠋ Container example-docker-compose-backend-2  Creating                          0.0s
Error response from daemon: make cli opts(): strconv.Atoi: parsing "8180-8280": invalid syntax
```

### 2. Without port range, address already in use conflict

Changed docker-compose.yml to remove port range

```
ports:
  - "8080:8080"
```

This results in port conflict, all 3 backend containers try to bind to 8080

```
Catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [190] milliseconds
Error response from daemon: rootlessport listen tcp 0.0.0.0:8080: bind: address already in use
```

### 3. Scale = 1

Let's try with just one backend container. System starts up

```
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                            COMMAND               CREATED        STATUS            PORTS                   NAMES
217c3e726431  docker.io/library/tomcat:latest  catalina.sh run       7 seconds ago  Up 6 seconds ago  0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp  example-docker-compose-backend-1
9c3f86676bde  docker.io/library/nginx:latest   nginx -g daemon o...  6 seconds ago  Up 6 seconds ago  0.0.0.0:3000->80/tcp    example-docker-compose-frontend-1
```

DNS from frontend server looks weird. What are all these different backend IP addresses 10.89.0.3 - 10.89.0.12? Only the last of them works when I `curl 10.89.0.x`. Still, `curl backend:8080` works fine?

### 4. Scale up from command line

I remove ports and scale from docker-compose.yml and start compose stack with scale=3 option:

```
version: "3"
services:
  frontend:
    image: "nginx:latest"
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
    depends_on:
      - backend
  backend:
    image: "tomcat:latest"

$ docker-compose up --scale backend=3
[+] Running 4/4
 ⠿ Container example-docker-compose-backend-2   Recreated                        0.3s
 ⠿ Container example-docker-compose-backend-3   Recreated                        0.2s
 ⠿ Container example-docker-compose-backend-1   Recreated                        0.3s
 ⠿ Container example-docker-compose-frontend-1  Recreated                        0.3s
Attaching to example-docker-compose-backend-1, example-docker-compose-backend-2, example-docker-compose-backend-3, example-docker-compose-frontend-1
```

Now compose stack starts nicely with 3 backend containers

```
$ docker ps
Emulate Docker CLI using podman. Create /etc/containers/nodocker to quiet msg.
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                            COMMAND               CREATED         STATUS             PORTS                 NAMES
b81c44246ae7  docker.io/library/tomcat:latest  catalina.sh run       22 minutes ago  Up 22 minutes ago                        example-docker-compose-backend-3
814dc5d307f7  docker.io/library/tomcat:latest  catalina.sh run       22 minutes ago  Up 22 minutes ago                        example-docker-compose-backend-2
fb0a5090a456  docker.io/library/tomcat:latest  catalina.sh run       22 minutes ago  Up 22 minutes ago                        example-docker-compose-backend-1
c0219d7fded4  docker.io/library/nginx:latest   nginx -g daemon o...  22 minutes ago  Up 22 minutes ago  0.0.0.0:3000->80/tcp  example-docker-compose-frontend-1
```

DNS from frontend has even more entries

```
# dig backend

; <<>> DiG 9.16.27-Debian <<>> backend
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 29526
;; flags: qr rd ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 11, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: 410008265c2b0edb (echoed)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;backend.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
backend.        86400   IN  A   10.89.0.3
backend.        86400   IN  A   10.89.0.4
backend.        86400   IN  A   10.89.0.6
backend.        86400   IN  A   10.89.0.7
backend.        86400   IN  A   10.89.0.15
backend.        86400   IN  A   10.89.0.16
backend.        86400   IN  A   10.89.0.18
backend.        86400   IN  A   10.89.0.19
backend.        86400   IN  A   10.89.0.20
backend.        86400   IN  A   10.89.0.21
backend.        86400   IN  A   10.89.0.22
```

And `curl backend:8080` does **not** work (not sure which port I should use now)

## Questions

1. What's going on here?
2. Can I achieve a setup of 3 backend containers, so that DNS name `backend` would resolve to those, with podman & docker-compose?
3. Podman seems to support docker-compose (or vice versa), but only to a degree. Is there some documentation which tells what docker-compose features are supported on Podman, and which are not?

Comment: After restarting the server, weirdness related to DNS is mostly gone, and dig returns sane results (without bunch of extra IP addresses) for backend, also curl backend:8080 works.

Comment: "mostly gone", since dig backend returns correct IP address, but host backend and nslookup backend can't find the server - which works on Ubuntu/docker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podman is my container runtime of choice...unless I'm working with docker-compose, in which case I have found it to be "close but not quite" in terms of its docker API support.

However, for what you're trying to do, you could replace Nginx with [Traefik](https://traefik.io/), and let Traefik handle the load balancing. Traefik is a dynamic proxy that uses the Docker API and container labelling to discover containers and configure the proxy rules.

For example:

```
version: "3"
services:
  frontend:
    image: "docker.io/traefik:v2.8"
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
      - "127.0.0.1:3080:8080"
    command:
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --providers.docker
    volumes:
      - /run/user/$UID/podman/podman.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

  backend:
    labels:
      traefik.http.routers.backend.rule: Host(`localhost`)
    image: "quay.io/larsks/demoserver:latest"
    scale: 3
```

Here we're mapping all requests for `Host: localhost` to to our backend containers. This is just for the purposes of a demonstration (since I'll be running `curl localhost/...`); a more realistic configuration would use specific hostnames, or paths, etc. You can read more in the [Routing configuration](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/providers/docker/#routing-configuration) section of Traefik's Docker documentation, and also in the general [Router](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/routers/) documentation.

With this configuration, we see the following containers running:

```
$ podman ps
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                             COMMAND               CREATED        STATUS            PORTS                                           NAMES
c29de1d137e2  docker.io/library/traefik:v2.8    --api.insecure=tr...  5 seconds ago  Up 6 seconds ago  0.0.0.0:3000->80/tcp, 127.0.0.1:3080->8080/tcp  demoserver_frontend_1
f4fac24cb494  quay.io/larsks/demoserver:latest  /usr/local/bin/st...  5 seconds ago  Up 6 seconds ago                                                  demoserver_backend_2
d9d388202be2  quay.io/larsks/demoserver:latest  /usr/local/bin/st...  5 seconds ago  Up 5 seconds ago                                                  demoserver_backend_1
5a3e6330739d  quay.io/larsks/demoserver:latest  /usr/local/bin/st...  5 seconds ago  Up 5 seconds ago                                                  demoserver_backend_3
```

And we can see that requests on port 3000 cycle between the available backends. Running this script:

```
for i in {1..10}; do
  curl http://localhost:3000/hostname
done
```

Produces as output:

```
5a3e6330739d
d9d388202be2
f4fac24cb494
5a3e6330739d
d9d388202be2
f4fac24cb494
5a3e6330739d
d9d388202be2
f4fac24cb494
5a3e6330739d
```

Comment: Thanks! Sounds like a really great fit for this sort of routing use case, I need study those links in detail.

Comment: Still, I would be like to understand why podman + docker-compose networking works like this, so I think I will keep this question open.

Comment: You've already identified the relevant bug. You *know* why the original config doesn't work in Podman. What else are you looking for?

Comment: For question 1, I would like to understand why DNS "backend" resolves to 11 different IP addresses on podman+docker-compose (and why I cannot curl any of them). For 2, any workaround would be nice, but I guess answer is "no, not until the bug is fixed", or is it? For 3, I would like to know if there's any source of documentation that describes the features that are supported by podman's docker-compose compatibility, instead of experimenting and using trial-and-error

Comment: Clarification: on the last, scaled up from command line, example backend resolves to 11 addresses. On the 3rd example (just one backend container) it for some reason resolves to 3 IP addresses (out of which only the last one works when I curl x.x.x.x with IP address)

Comment: Update: I retested and can't reproduce the weird DNS behavior with lots of extra backend IP addresses. It definitely happened, but I don't experience that anymore. dig resolves DNS names on RHEL/podman just like it does on Ubuntu/docker (although host and nslookup behave differently, but I guess there's a reason for that). This makes most of my question content noise. Even though the question is now bad, I guess this is as close to a correct answer as can be.

Comment: Tried, and traefik works nicely. I had to add privileged: true to the frontend container to prevent "Provider connection error Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock:" errors though. I am unsure about this, is running privileged container the correct way to go? I am running podman rootless on RHEL8. @larsks

Comment: You shouldn't require a privileged container in order to access the podman socket. It might be better to open a new question for that issue, because these comments are already quite long.

Comment: Certainly. I opened a new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73814619/permission-denied-trying-to-use-rootless-podman-docker-compose-traefik-with