# Permission denied trying to use rootless Podman + docker-compose + Traefik with podman.sock

Tags: docker-compose, traefik, podman, rootless

TL:DR: Trying to use rootless Podman with docker-compose through podman socket, and use a Traefik container (talking to podman socket) to proxy traffic to other containers, related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/73774327/1469083

I get permission denied errors, which I can fix with privileged container, which I don't want to use.

## Setup

I am running on RHEL 8

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.6 (Ootpa)
```

Podman came preinstalled, I added docker-compose ("standalone") and podman-docker:

```
$ curl -SL https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.10.2/docker-compose-linux-x86_64 -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
$ chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
$ sudo yum install podman-docker
```

And activated rootless podman socket so that podman and docker-compose can talk to each other:

```
$ systemctl --user enable podman.socket
$ systemctl --user start podman.socket
$ systemctl --user status podman.socket
$ export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///run/user/$UID/podman/podman.sock
$ echo $DOCKER_HOST
unix:///run/user/1001/podman/podman.sock
```

I also switched network backend to netavark, DNS did not work without that change

```
$ podman info |grep -i networkbackend
  networkBackend: netavark
```

## Problems

First I tried the compose stack from https://stackoverflow.com/a/73774327/1469083 with small modifications:

```
version: "3"
services:
  frontend:
    image: "docker.io/traefik:v2.8"
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
      - "127.0.0.1:3080:8080"
    command:
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --providers.docker
    volumes:
      - /run/user/$UID/podman/podman.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

  backend:
    labels:
      traefik.http.routers.backend.rule: Host(`localhost`)
    image: "tomcat:latest"
    scale: 3
```

My setup did not appreciate the `$UID` variable:

```
WARN[0000] The "UID" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
...
Error response from daemon: make cli opts(): error making volume mountpoint for volume /run/user//podman/podman.sock: mkdir /run/user//podman: permission denied
```

I replaced the volume map with hard-coded UID=1001 (it is the UID of the user running rootless podman, I assumed I should use that one?). Socket looks like this:

```
ls -la /run/user/1001/podman/podman.sock 
srw-rw----. 1 myrootlessuser myrootlessuser 0 22. 9. 11:28 /run/user/1001/podman/podman.sock


volumes:
  - /run/user/1001/podman/podman.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

But now I get permission denied errors from Traefik trying to connect to /var/run/docker.sock unsuccessfully:

```
example-docker-compose-frontend-1  | time="2022-09-22T12:04:52Z" level=error msg="Provider connection error Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get \"http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/version\": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied, retrying in 5.656635591s" providerName=docker
```

If I change the Traefik-container to `privileged: true`, this fixes the problem. I don't get the errors anymore, and proxying works like it should.

But, I would prefer not to use privileged containers for security reasons, or at least understand why it is like this.

## Questions

1. How can I make this work with non-privileged Traefik container?
2. How do I verify that rootless docker/podman socket is working correctly? I've seen commands like this for testing rootful podman socket, but haven't had success on rootless

   `$ sudo curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http://localhost/_ping`

   `curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server`
3. Where can I find the documentation for setting up docker socket for rootless Podman? Did I do my setup correctly (`systemctl --user enable podman.socket` etc.)? I've only been able to find some blogs about this, and advice varies and is often for older Podman versions. For example:

- https://fedoramagazine.org/use-docker-compose-with-podman-to-orchestrate-containers-on-fedora/ tells me to enable `podman.socket`
- https://earthly.dev/blog/earthly-podman/ tells me to enable `podman.service`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Question 1 and 2

If you are using

```
export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///run/user/$UID/podman/podman.sock
```

you are using rootless (unprivileged) Podman (even if you specify `privileged: true` in the Compose file).

To use the leaked socket in the container, you need to run `podman run` with the command-line option `--security-opt label=disable`.

Example:

Start and enable the podman socket

```
$ systemctl --user enable --now podman.socket
Created symlink /home/testuser/.config/systemd/user/sockets.target.wants/podman.socket → /usr/lib/systemd/user/podman.socket.
```

Test the Docker API service.
Result: failure. Curl prints `Couldn't connect to server`

```
$ podman run --rm \
  -v $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/podman/podman.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  docker.io/library/fedora \
    /usr/bin/curl \
      -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
      --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock \
        http://localhost/_ping
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
```

Test the Docker API service again, but now add `--security-opt label=disable`.
Result: success

```
$ podman run --rm \
  --security-opt label=disable \
  -v $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/podman/podman.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  docker.io/library/fedora \
    /usr/bin/curl \
      -Hs "Content-Type: application/json" \
      --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock \
        http://localhost/_ping
OK$
```

The Docker API service responded with the text string  *OK*.

(In the command above I also added the curl option **-s** so that curl prints less debug output)

I would guess that adding `privileged: true` to the Compose file has the same effect as providing the **--privileged** command-line option to `podman run`.

One of the effects of using  **--privileged** is that it implies **--security-opt label=disable**.

### Question 3

##### Summary:

It is enough to run

```
$ systemctl --user start podman.socket
```

to set up the UNIX socket for rootless Podman.

It's not necessary but if you in addition to that run

```
$ systemctl --user start podman.service
```

the podman.service will be started right away (even before the first client has connected to the UNIX socket).

##### Longer version:

If *podman.socket* is active, then the *podman.service* will be started when a client connects. (Podman supports *socket activation*)

The *podman.service* will also be started after a reboot if the *podman.service* has been enabled (`systemctl --user enable podman.service`) and lingering is enabled (`loginctl enable-linger`).

The *podman.service* will also be started when the user logs in if the *podman.service* has been enabled (`systemctl --user enable podman.service`).

The podman process running in the *podman.service* will automatically exit after some time of inactivity (by default 5 seconds).

On a Fedora 36 computer, the `Restart` directive is set to `no` (the default value):

```
$ grep Restart= /usr/lib/systemd/user/podman.service
$
```

This means that it really doesn't matter much whether

```
systemctl --user enable podman.service
```

has been run or not. The service *podman.service* will anyway be stopped in 5 seconds if no clients access it.

Comment: Thanks! Clarifies a lot. I will try to make sure I understand this correctly:

1. I'm using a rootless Podman setup for better security
2. Podman socket belongs to the same user who is running these containers
3. Without "privileged", SELinux prevents access to podman socket
4. Traefik container needs podman socket for dynamic routing to containers

Comment: And questions:

1. Does disabling SELinux make this as insecure as running rootful Podman (or Docker)
2. Is there any option that is less risky, ie. some kind of "only grant read access to podman socket"  3. You wrote "leaked socket" - why "leaked", is this a clear bad practice - AFAIK this is the only way to achieve dynamic routing with Traefik

Comment: Regarding the four statements in the first comment: I think they are correct.  Question 1 in your second comment: No. (An intruder would only get access to the user account but not the root account). Question 2: No, I don't think there is any "read-only" mode for the Docker API.  Question 3:  Not exactly the same use of the word, but it was used here https://twitter.com/rhatdan/status/1557432850349232128 in another context. (I just reused the terminology, although it was not exactly the same).

Comment: A tip if you are adventurous. (Disclaimer: I haven't tried out all of this yet). (Hopefully it could work). If you would like to go for safety (but probably giving up the dynamic funcionality) you could try to use nginx with socket activation (and use --network=none) https://github.com/eriksjolund/podman-nginx-socket-activation.    Official support will hopefully be released soon . I submitted a PR https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/pull/703.  The hosted websites would then be needed to be served via UNIX sockets via bind-mounted directories.